# regex doesn't catch the group

Tags: regex

Could anyone tell why group 1 below only catch "400" not "123"?
thanks!

pattern:

```
((\d+)\s*)+.*LC\s*$
```

text:

`123    400   LC`

"123 " match "((\d+)\s*)+" and others match ".*LC\s*$" seems to be works too? but why regex don't use this?

Comment: What is the language or tool?

Comment: If flavor supports lookaheads you are in luck [`(\d+)\s*(?=.*LC\s*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/jWBbwa/1)

Comment: i tested in python and a small too Expresso which maybe use .net language

Comment: Then that regex work for you. Be sure to set `m` flag: `(?m)(\d+)\s*(?=.*LC\s*$)`. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach doesn't capture each sequence of digits separately because you are repeating a pattern which leaves one match (last match) to be in capturing group. Besides, without repeating pattern, regex flavor wouldn't re-try a match while following characters are all consumed with `.*`.

If your flavor supports lookaheads you are in luck:

```
(\d+)\s*(?=.*LC\s*$)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jWBbwa/1)

Comment: thanks! not understand, as nested group works for "400  LC", why regex can just treat "400" as ".*" then it get "123"?

Comment: Accessing to each part matched by a repeating capturing group is not possible in Python (but available in .NET).

Comment: If this solution helped and was right you may consider up-voting or accepting answer by clicking on check mark and up-arrow icons at the left. @FelixLiu

Comment: Thanks, just tried to accept your answer, but get reminder my reputation is less than 15, so it is just recorded...

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\d)+/g
```

This regex will work if you only want to capture the numbers in the given text.

Edit: If you want to consider LC and space as well, then try this regex:

```
/(\d+[^LC\s*])/g
```

Explanation for the same:
[image]

Comment: i need LC because the text from multiple lines, i just the line with LC\s*$ end

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying that after the (("one or more digits")"whitespace") there will be any characters maybe and then an "LC"

if you want to catch all of the numbers you can just say (\d+)

you can check your stuff here  http://pythex.org/

Comment: "123  " match "((\d+)\s*)+"  and others match ".*LC\s*$" seems to be works too? but why regex don't use this?